# Return out of a void function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a `read()` function with an arrow-function as a parameter.
If I implement the function like this, the value is shown in the console as it should.

```
function(path: string) {
    this.db.read(path, val => {
      console.log(val.value)
    });
}
```

My question is, how can I get the value out of this function?

I tried it in several return ways, but nothing was worked.

```
//This is not working...
function(path: string) {
  newValue = this.db.read(path, val => {
      console.log(val.value)
      return val.value;
    });
  return newValue;
}

//Is working, but not really good...
private newValue;

function(path: string) {
  this.db.read(path, val => {
      console.log(val.value)
      this.newValue = val.value;
    });
  return this.newValue;
}
```

Maybe someone can give me a hint on how to do that.

Comment: Does the `read()` function evaluate the passed callback immediately?

Comment: Have you tried this : `return this.db.read(path, val => {
      console.log(val.value)
      return val.value;
    });`
instead of `newValue = this.db.read(path, val => {
      console.log(val.value)
      return val.value;
    });
  return newValue;`

Comment: Async functions needs to be handled using promises.

Answer (score 4):

Try this approach. Return new Promise instead of val that you will get in some future time.:

```
function readDb(path: string) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    this.db.read(path, val => {
      resolve(val.value);
    });
  });
}
this.readDb("/path").then(function(val) { console.log(val) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is related `Asynchronous` calls. So its very important that you play with `Observable`, `Callback` and `Subscription`.

Since `read` returns the Observable already, you don't need to create new one.

### What needs to be changed ?

So that needs to be changed in your code. All is fine except the way you are calling it. Do not return the value instead let it return the `Observable`.

### Solution 1

```
readData(path){
   new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      this.db.read(path, val => {
          let readValue = val.value;  //<-- you can choose what you want to return.
          resolve(readValue);
       });
   });
```

//usage

```
readData("/path/of/db").then(value=>{
   console.log(value); //value is here once the DB call is completed.
});
```

### Solution 2

The same thing can be achieved by Observable if you want to notify you every time new data is received.

private _subject: Subject = new Subject();

```
readData(path){
      this.db.read(path, val => {
          let readValue = val.value;  //<-- you can choose what you want to return.
          subject.next(readValue);
       });
}
```

### usage

```
this.subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Data from DB ', data);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

the 2nd solution you gave is the way to achieve that.

When you do this.newValue = val.value; you affect the value you get from your read function to the variable newValue, which is exactly what you want, therefore the value is already outside of the function.

```
private newValue;

function(path: string) {
  this.db.read(path, val => {
    this.newValue = val.value;
  });
}
```

You don't need to return anything here since you already have the value stored on your private variable newValue.

Comment: Assuming read is asynchronous this would lead to serious problems, because nothing guarantees when the callback might get executed, if he tries to use that variable right after it might not have the expected value yet. A Promise should be used in this case or Observables